# How to Keep Escape Sequence from User Input (C#)

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

When we declare a string that contain escape sequence, we can use @ in front of the string.

```
string fulljob = @"division\jobtitle";
```

But how if the string value come from user input. I need to query :

```
public string GetContactName(string fulljob)
    {

        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("contact");
        string[] cols = { "jobtitle", "lastname" };
        query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
        query.Criteria.AddCondition("jobtitle", ConditionOperator.Equal, fulljob);
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(cols);

        EntityCollection ec = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        string tes = string.Empty;

        foreach (Entity en in ec.Entities)
        {
            tes = tes + en["lastname"].ToString();
        }
        return tes;
    }
```

We get `string fulljob` from user input. When we run the query above, it's give me error becasue there is escape sequence inside the string:

> Condition for attribute 'contact.jobtitle': null is not a valid value for an attribute. Use 'Null' or 'NotNull' conditions instead.

Comment: looks like `fulljob` is actually null value - how do you get it from input? You might consider adding validation of input param in method, or make `query.Criteria.AddCondition("jobtitle", ConditionOperator.Equal, fulljob);` conditional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
query.Criteria.AddCondition("jobtitle", ConditionOperator.Equal, fulljob);
```

by this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fulljob))
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("jobtitle", ConditionOperator.Null);
else
    query.Criteria.AddCondition("jobtitle", ConditionOperator.Equal, fulljob);
```